How to preserve the correct values in a date-column when using summarize() from dplyr?
I am using summarize() to transform one dataframe (cid_term) to another one (row_1dyadep). I want to receive one row for each value of a grouping variable (new_dyadep_id). For many of the variables, I want to use the last non-NA value in the summarized output (because they are either NA or all the same anyway). My problem is that one of these variables is a date column (ependdate), and I have not been able to preserve it in the correct form. For example, the value in the first data-frame "1991-10-10" becomes "7952" after summarization.
This is the code I used:
row_1dyadep <- cid_term %>%
  group_by(new_dyadep_id) %>%
  summarize(
    new_dyadep_id = last(new_dyadep_id),
    dyad_id = ifelse(all(is.na(dyad_id)), NA, last(dyad_id[!is.na(dyad_id)], default = NA)),
    location = ifelse(all(is.na(location)), NA, last(location[!is.na(location)], default = NA)),
    first_year_active = ifelse(all(is.na(first_year_active)), NA, last(first_year_active[!is.na(first_year_active)], default = NA)),
    last_year_active = ifelse(all(is.na(last_year_active)), NA, last(last_year_active[!is.na(last_year_active)], default = NA)),
    ependdate = ifelse(all(is.na(ependdate)), NA, last(ependdate[!is.na(ependdate)], default = NA)),
    incompatibility = ifelse(all(is.na(incompatibility)), NA, last(incompatibility[!is.na(incompatibility)], default = NA)),
    conflict_id = ifelse(all(is.na(conflict_id)), NA, last(conflict_id[!is.na(conflict_id)], default = NA)),
    side_a = ifelse(all(is.na(side_a)), NA, last(side_a[!is.na(side_a)], default = NA)),
    side_b = ifelse(all(is.na(side_b)), NA, last(side_b[!is.na(side_b)], default = NA)),
    conflict = ifelse(all(is.na(conflict)), NA, last(conflict[!is.na(conflict)], default = NA)),
    dyadepisode = ifelse(all(is.na(dyadepisode)), NA, last(dyadepisode[!is.na(dyadepisode)], default = NA)),
    outcome = ifelse(all(is.na(outcome)), NA, last(outcome[!is.na(outcome)], default = NA)),
    territory_name = ifelse(all(is.na(territory_name)), NA, last(territory_name[!is.na(territory_name)], default = NA)),
    region = ifelse(all(is.na(region)), NA, last(region[!is.na(region)], default = NA)),
    last_dyadcount = ifelse(all(is.na(dyadcount)), NA, last(dyadcount[!is.na(dyadcount)], default = NA)),
    max_dyadcount = max(dyadcount, na.rm = TRUE),
    last_intensity_level = ifelse(all(is.na(intensity_level)), NA, last(intensity_level[!is.na(intensity_level) & active_year == 1], default = NA)),
    max_intensity_level = max(intensity_level, na.rm = TRUE),
    last_type_of_conflict = ifelse(all(is.na(type_of_conflict)), NA, last(type_of_conflict[!is.na(type_of_conflict)], default = NA)),
    max_type_of_conflict = max(type_of_conflict, na.rm = TRUE),
    avg_issue_count_per_year = mean(issue_count_per_year, na.rm = TRUE),
    obs_years_per_episode = n(), # nrows per episode
    across(all_of(issue_columns), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names = "freq_{col}"),
    across(starts_with("ethnicity"), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, last(.x[!is.na(.x)], default = NA)), .names = "{col}"),
    across(starts_with("geography"), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, last(.x[!is.na(.x)], default = NA)), .names = "{col}"),
    across(starts_with("ideology"), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, last(.x[!is.na(.x)], default = NA)), .names = "{col}"),
    across(starts_with("religion"), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, last(.x[!is.na(.x)], default = NA)), .names = "{col}")
  )

The relevant line (I suppose) is the one starting with ependdate. Note that using a combination of last() and na-omit() (as ChatGPT has been proposing) does not work, because then I end up with less rows in row_1dyadep than I have unique values of new_dyadep_id. I think because with that code, groups of new_dyadep_id that show only NAs in ependdate would be dropped entirely which I want to avoid.

October 10th, 1991 was 7,952 days after January 1st, 1970. You can go back to a date format with as.Date(7952, origin="1970-01-01").

Less code and a little sample data for your next SO question!
Here it is:
(toy data at the end)
Original and proposed takes:
library(tidyverse)

# Original
original_output <- my_df %>% 
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  summarize(
    some_date = ifelse(
      all(is.na(some_date)), 
      NA, 
      last(some_date[!is.na(some_date)], default = NA)))

# Proposed
new_output <- my_df %>% 
  summarise(
    .by = group_id,
    last_date = last(some_date, na_rm = TRUE))

The outputs:
# An output like yours:
> original_output
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   group_id some_date
      <int>     <dbl>
 1        1        NA
 2        2     19996
 3        3     20112
 4        4     20226
 5        5     20169
 6        6     19896
 7        7     19911
 8        8     20169
 9        9     20198
10       10     20087

# `dplyr::last`s output is well behaved
> new_output
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   group_id last_date 
      <int> <date>    
 1        1 NA        
 2        2 2024-09-30
 3        3 2025-01-24
 4        4 2025-05-18
 5        5 2025-03-22
 6        6 2024-06-22
 7        7 2024-07-07
 8        8 2025-03-22
 9        9 2025-04-20
10       10 2024-12-30


Toy data:
set.seed(13)
my_df <- tibble(
  group_id = sort(rep.int(1:10, 3)),
  some_date = sample(today() + 0:365, 30, replace = TRUE))

my_df$some_date[sample(1:30, 12)] <- NA

> my_df
# A tibble: 30 × 2
   group_id some_date 
      <int> <date>    
 1        1 NA         #
 2        1 NA         # All NAs
 3        1 NA         #
 4        2 NA        
 5        2 NA        
 6        2 2024-09-30
 7        3 2025-04-06
 8        3 2024-12-28
 9        3 2025-01-24
10        4 NA        
11        4 2025-05-18
12        4 NA        
13        5 2025-02-24
14        5 2024-05-26
15        5 2025-03-22
16        6 2024-07-14
17        6 NA        
18        6 2024-06-22
19        7 NA        
20        7 2024-09-23
21        7 2024-07-07
22        8 NA        
23        8 2025-03-22
24        8 NA        
25        9 NA        
26        9 2024-08-16
27        9 2025-04-20
28       10 2024-07-21
29       10 2024-09-29
30       10 2024-12-30

Created on 2024-05-22 with reprex v2.1.0
